# Laptop not charging when running OS/BIOS, charges when off

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, bios, power-supply, battery

I am facing this problem in my laptop since last 3 days or so.
Make : HP Envy Touchsmart 15 (Core i7, 4700MQ), approx 1.5 years old.
The problem is that whenever I am running any OS (Win/Ubuntu), charging becomes AC power (doesn't charge, keeps battery constant). But when I shutdown the laptop, it charges perfectly. (Hp laptops show red right for charging and white for not charging or when fully charged).

Sometimes this problem goes off automatically when I start the computer. First I thought there's some issue with windows battery driver. But since I noticed it in Ubuntu also, I am quite worried. So is the issue related to the battery or something else ?

PS. I have tried this method (twice) but it didn't work for me: Uninstall Microsoft Battery Drivers from device manager->restart on AC (without battery)->start again with battery.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Gagan

Comment: Have you tried a battery pull? Could also be defective motherboard (there is an entire power switching logic that takes care of AC or DC power and charging). Had once a defective laptop that was charging when off and running from battery when on.

Comment: hey Dan ! what do you mean by battery ? is it anything different from removing and replugging the battery ?

Comment: No it's exactly that (similar to what you would do to a smarphone gone south), unplung, remove battery, wait a minute, put all back.

Comment: tried. Still the problem comes 1/3 times I start my laptop.